# How to search for all message of a single user in Telegram?

Tags: telegram

In Web version of Telegram, How to search for all messages which are posted by a single user in Telegram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both Desktop and Android - open your group chat and select search (the magnifying glass or search button). Then, you'll have two icons - calendar and profile/person. Choose the profile to search by person, and calendar to search by date. In the desktop version the icon are in the search field, and in Android they are at the bottom.

— [arieljannai](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/177684/arieljannai)
[Apr 6, 2018 at 9:56](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/116007/how-to-search-for-all-message-of-a-single-user-in-telegram/169836#comment103985_116054) [comment section]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible yet <sup>(*)</sup> in the official [Telegram Web](https://web.telegram.org/) without any hacks or modifications.

(*) ***yet***, because eventually all Telegram clients should support the same functionality (more or less, depends on the platform).

Comment: Thanks, do you mean it's possible in other versions of Telegram? Is it possible in Windows version of Telegram?

Comment: Yes, it's possible on the desktop and mobile versions. Keep in mind you can search for it in specific chats, not in general. If you meant in general, then I misunderstood you - and it's not possible at all.

Comment: Can you explain how it's possible in the Windows/Android version of Telegram? I mean for example in a group I would like to see all post of a specific user.

Comment: In both Desktop and Android - open your group chat and select search (the magnifying glass or `search` button). Then, you'll have two icons - calendar and profile/person. Choose the profile to search by person, and calendar to search by date. In the desktop version the icon are in the search field, and in Android they are at the bottom.

Comment: As a caveat, this method only works for those users still in the group, it uses the current group membership. So if you wanted to find all the posts by a member that was in the group six months ago but left, it won't allow you to enter their name.